# How query metric value at 0:00 of the day by using Prometheus PromQL

Tags: prometheus, promql

prometheus gets metric value at 0:00 of the day for example:  the metric name is eseal_num_total, Why write like 'eseal_num_total @ (time()-(time()+28800)%86400)' and execute Promql 'eseal_num_total @ (time()-(time()+28800)%86400)',this get an syntax error? Why is the syntax wrong? Can it be written correctly? who can help me,thank you?

I added an metric named eseal_num_total, and the PromQL query expression I tried was 'eseal_num_total @ (time()-(time()+28800)%86400)', and I wanted to get the metric value at 0:00 of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Prometheus doesn't support arbitrary expressions as an argument to [@ modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#modifier). That's why it returns syntax error for `eseal_num_total @ (time()-(time()+28800)%86400)`.

If you need this functionality, then try [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - this is Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on. It supports math expressions for `@` modifier, so the query above works as expected. Additionally, it supports duration constants in arbitrary places of the query. For example, the following query returns the `eseal_num_total` metric value at `08:00 UTC`:

```
eseal_num_total @ (time() - (time() + 8h) % 1d)
```

You can try this functionality at [VictoriaMetrics playground](https://play.victoriametrics.com/select/accounting/1/6a716b0f-38bc-4856-90ce-448fd713e3fe/prometheus/graph/?g0.expr=sum(rate(process_cpu_seconds_total))%20%40%20(end()%20-%20end()%20%25%201d)&g0.range_input=2d&g0.end_input=2023-02-01T22%3A22%3A10&g0.relative_time=last_2_days&g1.expr=sum(rate(process_cpu_seconds_total))&g1.range_input=2d&g1.end_input=2023-02-01T22%3A22%3A10&g1.relative_time=last_2_days).

Additionally, VictoriaMetrics provides convenient function for working with  timezone offsets - [timezone_offset()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#timezone_offset).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, prometheus is a framework that has been studied and studied for a long time, and the cost of changing the framework midway is a bit high, so prometheus has to continue to use.

Comment: VictoriaMetrics is almost a drop-in replacement for Prometheus: just change the data source url in Grafana from Prometheus to VictoriaMetrics - and all the dashboards should continue working. It also supports Prometheus configs for automatic discovering and scraping of Prometheus-compatible targets. additionally, it supports Prometheus configs for alerting and recording rules via vmselect component.

Comment: Does VictoriaMetrics support as a data source for grafana and display information through grafana? Does it support integration with spring? Does it support pushgateway and exporter mechanisms? Sorry I haven't read the introduction to VictoriaMetrics

Comment: The answer is yes for all three questions

Comment: Are there any references for these three issues? I don't seem to see a VictoriaMetrics data source that can be added in the grafana community edition

Comment: Just use Prometheus data source in Grafana - https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Single-server-VictoriaMetrics.html#grafana-setup

Comment: As for the integration with Pushgateway, see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Single-server-VictoriaMetrics.html#how-to-import-data-in-prometheus-exposition-format